# Set jQuery.countdown Multiple instances on the same page with Timezone Aware (MomentJS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-countdown

I need to set `jQuery.countdown` Multiple instances on the same page with Timezone Aware using MomentJS as per the documentation in the website:

So far I have this:

```
<div data-countdown="2018-01-01 12:00:00"></div>
<div data-countdown="2019-01-01 12:00:00"></div>
<div data-countdown="2020-01-01 12:00:00"></div>

<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

    jQuery("[data-countdown]").each(function() {

        var jQuerythis = jQuery(this), finalDate = jQuery(this).data("countdown");

        finalDate = moment.tz(finalDate, "Europe/London"); // <-- ***THIS IS NOT WORKING***

        jQuerythis.countdown(finalDate, function(event) {           
            jQuerythis.html(event.strftime("%D days %H:%M:%S"));            
        });

    });

});             
</script>
```

But it is not working. I don't think the follwing line is overall correct:

```
finalDate = moment.tz(finalDate, "Europe/London");
```

MomentJS is installed properly and if I remove the one line above everything works but without timezone awareness.

Could you provide with some suggestions please?

Comment: What format is `finalDate` ?

Comment: format: Y-m-d H:i:s . I updated the code in the question. It works but I am trying to make it timezone aware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To whoever needs it, I was missing this portion "`.toDate()`" in the following line:

```
jQuerythis.countdown(finalDate.toDate(), function(event) {
```

So now everything works beautifully!

I found the solution with help from this blog article [Final Countdown jQuery plugin Multiple instances on the same page with Timezone Aware](https://www.kmbytes.com/set-jquery-countdown-multiple-instances-page-timezone-aware/)

jQuery.countdown Multiple instances on the same page with Timezone Aware (MomentJS).

Thanks to everybody that helped!